# Can not hook keydown event after using setContentView of nswindow

Tags: objective-c, keydown

After I set content of window as a video view which is a nsview, I cannot hook keydown event

```
[self.myWindow setContentView:videoView];
```

Keydown method cannot hook

```
-(void)keyDown:(NSEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"aaaaaaa");
}
```

I am not aware of this issue. Could you explain to me what happened to my code?

Comment: Where did you implement `keyDown:`? Does `videoView` handle the keydown event?

Answer (score 0):

after using 

 [self.myWindow setContentView:videoView];

 the current nsview is lost, and it is the reason we cannot hook keydown method in current nsview. it must be hooked in VideoView